# Coefficient of friction greater than one

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

Can coefficient of static or kinetic friction be greater than one?

If yes, then is there example of any material which is practically in use?

Comment: Check out the Engineering Toolbox website.!for example they indicate a static friction value of 2.05-1.35 for clean and dry aluminum to aluminum contact

Comment: Thanks . It's helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is coefficient of friction is always less than unity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331080/)