# Are coefficients of friction the same in different gravitational fields?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, friction

For objects resting flat with $F_N = mg$, both gravity $g$ and coefficients of static friction $\mu_s$ play into calculating friction force by:

$$F_{friction} = \mu_s F_N = \mu_s mg$$

This equation implies that gravity and coefficients of static friction are equally interchangeable in determining friction force. But here is an example where I have a hard time believing that:

$\mu_s$ between ice and ice = 0.09 
$\mu_s$ between rubber and dry asphalt = 0.9

Imagine two identical blocks, one sitting on two pieces of ice on the surface of Earth (gravity = $1.0g$) and the other sitting on a piece of rubber on dry asphalt on the surface of a planet with 1/10th Earth's gravity ($0.1g$).  then by:

$$F_{friction\ Earth} = \mu_s F_N = (0.09)(m)(1.0g)=0.09\ mg$$
$$F_{friction\ Other Planet} = \mu_s  F_N = (0.9)(m)(0.1g)= 0.09\ mg$$

Since the friction force is the same, they should behave the same way when I push them, right? But this goes against my intuition... at 1/10th the gravity of Earth, would rubber really slide around around on dry asphalt like ice? Or do the coefficients of friction need adjustment if you switch the gravity?

---

Coefficients of static friction from [EngineeringToolbox.com](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/friction-coefficients-d_778.html)

Comment: -1 Why do you think rubber would not slide like ice in low $g$ environments? What is the source of your *intuition* about this?

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of friction does not depend on the origin of the normal force $\vec{F}_N$ so also not by the gravitational field that caused it. See [How is frictional force dependent on normal reaction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/260979/how-is-frictional-force-dependent-on-normal-reaction) for how a normal force can cause a friction force perpendicular to it.